# Clear AceFEM memory

Tags: finite-element-method, acegen

I am doing multiple AceFEM simulations by invoking the mathematica notebooks using NotebookEvaluate. After a number of simulations everything breaks down, I suppose the problem is too much memory occupied.

Is there any command that enables to clear the memory after finishing the AceFEM simulation? I don't think Quit[] is an option here since I want the kernel to keep invoking subsequent notebooks.

Comment: That's a bit vague. Try to set `$HistoryLength=0` or `Clear` variables that occupy a lot of memory.

Comment: You should also identify where you are loosing the memory. There are three different executables running (see task manager)  Wolfram mathematica, Wolfram kernel, AceFEM Driver.  If you are loosing the memory in AceFEM Driver then it is AceFEM related problem, otherwise it is probably Mathematica related problem.